# Inequality about number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality

I have a little question about number theory :

Let $ a $, $ b $, $ c $ be positive nonzero integers such that $ a \geq b \geq c $ we put:

$a-b = \epsilon$, $b-c = \epsilon$ (to say that there is the same difference between each variable)

Let the sum $ a ^ 2b + b ^ 2c + c ^ 2a-a ^ 2c-c ^ 2b-b ^ 2a = \beta $

How to show that the sum resulting from the addition of each digit composing the number $ \beta $ is greater than the sum resulting from the addition of each digit composing the number $ \epsilon $ where $ \epsilon \geq 100 $?

Edit : replace the 0 by 9 in the number composing $2\epsilon^3$

Thanks a lot .

Comment: I found this theorem is it relevant ? 
If N is a positive integer , $N=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i10^i$ , $n> 2$ , $a_i$ an integer , $0\leq a_i \leq 9$ , $a_n \neq 0$  and $0\leq i \leq 9$ then:
$$N\geq \frac{1\overbrace{0\cdots0}_{}^{k+1}\overbrace{9\cdots9}_{}^{n-k}}{1+9(n-k-1)}A_n$$
Where $A_n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i$, and $k$ is unique integer such that :
$2+\sum_{i=0}^{k}10^i\leq n \leq 2+\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}10^i$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that $\beta=(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)$, which is $2(a-b)^3$, because $c=2b-a$.

Comment: The real challenge seems to prove that digit sum of $2\epsilon^3$ always exceeds that of $\epsilon$, which is highly likely given the additional digits, but hard to say for certain.